# Failed to convert parameter value string to a IEnumerable

Tags: c#, sql, dictionary

I have a Dictionary. I am only trying to grab the keys and use them to update a database.

```
foreach (string key in dt.Keys)
{
    var param = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_AccountList", key);
    var paddingParam = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@padding", padding);
    var dateStartParam = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proc_dateStart", startDate);
    var dateEndParam = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proc_dateEnd", endDate);
    //table valued parameters
    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    var reader = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The data type in my stored procedure is `varchar`, which should work. I'm not sure why it wants to convert my keys to IEnumerable. Could it have something to do with using Table valued Parameters?

Comment: What type does your `@_AccountList` parameter have ?

Comment: `SqlDbType.Structured` is good when you want to pass `DataTable` as a parameter.

Comment: You also seem to be adding the parameters multiple times.  Do you clear the `Parameters` collection between each iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 4):

You `param` variable holds a parameter of type `NVarChar` (implicitly), because `key` is a string, but then you set its type to `SqlDbType.Structured` for some reason. Because of that, the data provider tries to iterate through the value, but cannot, because the value is just of type `string`.